# Broken Intellisense in One VS2010 Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, intellisense

I have a solution that contains several projects, and **all but one project loads full intellisense**. The one project left is a C# class library and does have some intellisense, so I still get simple syntax and structs, but nothing useful like ObservableCollection, Go to Definition, list members, or parameter info. I can't even get intellisense on the properties in the current class.

Is there a log somewhere of what error caused intellisense not to work that would help me in this case?

Here is a list of the things that I have tried and have not worked for me:

- Restarting my machine
- devenv /resetuserdata
- Tool -> Options, Text Editor -> All Languages -> Auto list members is selected

Comment: This sounds like the kind of flaky IntelliSense that us C++ devs have to put up with. I have yet to see this for a C# solution. Only thing I can think of to try that you haven't mentioned is running a full clean and rebuild for your solution—possibly the IntelliSense cache got corrupted somehow?

Comment: @CodyGray I did indeed run a clean and attempt to rebuild. However, we don't normally build from Visual Studio, so that is a difficult proposition. None of the projects build, but that doesn't seem to affect most of them, where intellisense continues to work. It's only one project that does not work.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper? If so, close the solution, delete the _ReSharper.* directory under the solution directory, reopen the solution, and see if that helped. Sometimes ReSharper gets confused due to a corrupted cache, and all sorts of strange intellisense behavior can result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on the project and started a new project file, which worked. The only thing I can figure is that the project file got corrupted. When looking at the differences between the old file and the new file, it looks likes the structure encompassing many of the files was changed, possibly a difference between VS2008 and VS2010.